# ConnectionString from app.config of a DLL is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config

I have a class library that contains a valid connectionString inside the app.config. Inside that class library I want to use it with

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NAME"].ConnectionString
```

My ASP.net 4.0 framework application references that DDL and retrieves data from it. I want create a Entity Framework 4 DataContext within my DDL with the ConnectionString from the App.config. (I do not want to pass the connectionString from my ASP.net application in every single method. (I'm using ObjectDataSources))

However, this line inside my DLL throws a NullReferenceException.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NAME"].ConnectionString
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Am i the only one who finds it funny that Chuck was here too???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a class library that contains a
>   valid connectionString inside the
>   app.config

A class library doesn't have an app.config file associated. It's the application consuming this assembly that does. So you need to put the connection string inside this config file (if this is an ASP.NET application this would be `web.config`). Thus adding an `App.config` file in a project of type class library in Visual Studio makes no sense.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks. But why is the app.config autogenerated?

Comment: @citronas - It has other uses (*that* project doesn't know where it's doing, possibly in *other* solutions), unit testing the library for example.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you put the same [`<connectionStrings>` entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) (the `<add>` in question) in your web app's `web.config`, [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) always looks at the current config, that's a web.config in your case.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you don't waana use `ConfigurationManager`

If i assume the config file is `mydll.dll.config` i can load it as `XElement` and parse it using Linq as

```
var xe = XElement.Load("mydll.dll.config");
var connectionString = xe.Descendants("connectionStrings")
     .Elements("add")
     .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("name").Value == Name)
     .Attribute("connectionString").Value;
```

where `Name` is the connectionString name in the XML. Without using the  `ConfigurationManager` import and other stuffs. The only requirement for this to make sure that the config file sit next to the dll.