# Get connection string from App.config

Tags: c#, ado.net, exception, connection-string, app-config

```
var connection = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"]
    .ConnectionString, DataBaseProvider);
```

And this is my App.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But when my project runs this is my error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where did you put that App.config? Project of application you're running or maybe some dll? You need first

Comment: Add a reference to System.Configuration.dll, and you should be able to use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Your connection string has a typo. You need a space between "Integrated" and "Security"

Comment: @OnurOmer - question has been updated to include the space ("Integrated Security" instead of "IntegratedSecurity")

Answer (score 555):

You can just do the following:

```
var connection = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
```

Your assembly also needs a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`

Comment: I know that this is a C# question, but since this is the top of the google search results, to do this in VB, it's `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Test").ConnectionString` for those of us who have to maintain VB code

Answer (score 319):

Since this is very common question I have prepared some screen shots from Visual Studio to make it easy to follow in 4 simple steps.

[image: get connection string from app.config]

Comment: Love this answer. By default in my version of VS (VS2012 Ultimate) this library is not included, but `using System.Configuration` still works

Comment: I really HAD TO add the reference or the using was not underlined but still ConfigurationManager unknown. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

```
string str = Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString;
```

Comment: What if app.config is added as a link to a project ?

Comment: This will only work if your connection string is an app setting, it will not work if to retrieve `<connectionStrings>` elements from app.config (which is what the OP is asking for!).

Answer (score 33):

Also check that you've included the `System.Configuration` dll under your references. Without it, you won't have access to the `ConfigurationManager` class in the System.Configuration namespace.

Answer (score 31):

First Add a reference of `System.Configuration` to your page.

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then According to your **app.config** get the connection string as follow.

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString();
```

That's it now you have your connection string in your hand and you can use it.

Answer (score 17):

```
//Get Connection from web.config file
public static OdbcConnection getConnection()
{
    OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    return con;     
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this out

```
string abc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CharityManagement"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
string connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
```

Outputs:

> Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;IntegratedSecurity=True"

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
var connection = new ConnectionFactory().GetConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"]
    .ConnectionString, DataBaseProvider);
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Create a new form and add this:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Operaciones.My.MySettings

Public NotInheritable Class frmconexion

    Private Shared _cnx As String
    Public Shared Property ConexionMySQL() As String
        Get
            Return My.MySettings.Default.conexionbd
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As String)
            _cnx = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

then when you want to use the connection do this in ur form:

```
 Private Sub frmInsert_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(frmconexion.ConexionMySQL)
cn.open()
```

and thats it. You will be connected to the DB and can do stuff.

This is for vb.net but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the OP in this question is trying to use an App.Config within a dll.

In this case, the code is actually trying to access the App.Config of the executable and not the dll.  Since the name is not found, you get a Null returned, hence the exception shown.

The following post may be helpful:
[ConnectionString from app.config of a DLL is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641896/connectionstring-from-app-config-of-a-dll-is-null)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Issue. my solution was built up from two projects. A `Class library` and a website referencing to the class library project. the problem was that i was trying to access the `App.config` in my `Class library` project but the system was searching in `Web.config` of the website. I put the connection string inside `Web.config` and ... problem solved!

The main reason was that despite `ConfigurationManager` was used in another assembly it was searching inside the runnig project .

Answer (score 3):

The answers above didn't elaborate ***where*** the value in connectionStrings index comes from.

As mentioned above, to get your connection string, you say:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ToString();
```

To use the correct value of `XXX`, go to your main projects `web.config` file and look for the following piece of code:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Authentication" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Authentication;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Authentication.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Where it says `name=` , the text within those proceeding quotes is the value of `XXX` you use in the code above. In my example above, it happens to be `Authentication`

Answer (score 2):

```
string sTemp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB In app.config"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like problem is not with reference, you are getting connectionstring as null so please make sure you have added the value to the config file your running project meaning the main program/library that gets started/executed first.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to add `System.Configuration` reference to your project and then use below code to get connection string.

```
_connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYSQLConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to get connection string

```
using System; 
using System.Configuration;

private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the connection string by using below line of code -

```
using System; using System.Configuration;

var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Here is a reference : 
[Connection String from App.config](http://programmers.bhoomijunction.com/Article/connection-string-from-app-config-web-config-in-csharp-or-asp-net-31)

Comment: I did the same as u said but same null reference error I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

I referenced `System.Configuration` library and I have the same error.
The debug files had not their app.config, create manually this file.
The error is, I solved this copying the file "appname.exe.config" in debug folder. The IDE was not create the file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the index to read the string and checking one by one. Reading using the name still gives the same error.
I have the problem when I develop a C# window application, I did not have the problem in my asp.net application. There must be something in the setting which is not right.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read the connection string from app.cfg (in windows service application) the below code worked for me

```
 var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTIONSTR"].ConnectionString = @"New Connection String";
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue while placing `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` in **UserControl**'s constructor, and none of the solution here worked for me.

After some research, seems like `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` would be null while trying to access it from the `DesignTime`.

And from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166547/8140473), I came up with this following code to detect `DesignTime` as a workaround to the issue:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl 
{
    ....
    public MyUserControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
        if (!designMode)
        {
            this.connectionString = 
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```