# how to get connection string from app config in c#

Tags: c#

My app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MegaPixelBizConn"
            connectionString="Data Source=PSHERATH-PC;Initial Catalog=MegaPixelBiz;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then I created DBConnection file:

```
class DBConnection
    {
        #region Database connection method
        public SqlConnection Connect()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"].ToString();

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

this is my login form:

```
SqlCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtUserName.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
                {
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                    lblError.Text = "*Enter UserName and Password";
                    //MessageBox.Show(" Enter UserName and Password .");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE userName = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' and password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, db.Connect());
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        Home hm = new Home();
                        hm.Show();
                        ds.Clear();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblError.Text = "*Not Registered User or Invalid Name/Password";
                        //MessageBox.Show("Not Registered User or Invalid Name/Password");
                        txtPassword.Text = "";
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

But when my project run, this error come:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
please give me a solution. I use all suitable references

Comment: Are you able to read the connections string while debugging?

Comment: Does your error happen on the line `conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"].ToString();`?

Comment: yes, error happen on the line `conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"].ToString();`

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Alright, I try my latest edit to see if it fixes your problem (my main pc is broken and I have Ubuntu on laptop so haven't bothered testing).

Comment: Is this a web project that uses `Web.config` instead of `app.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringNameFromWebConfig"].ConnectionString);
```

It should work

Comment: Tip: It can be quite helpful to wrap the `ConfigurationManager` methods for retrieving application settings and connections strings with code that throws an exception if the requested value is not found in the configuration file. An exception that says `Connection string "SecretDB" not found in configuration.` is a real time saver compared to chasing another `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 4):

Basing my answer on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536715/get-connection-string-from-app-config), try:

```
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"].ConnectionString;
```

Make sure you have a reference to `System.Configuration` as well.

Also remember to close your `connection`.

**EDIT**

Based on your new edit, try this for your code (Note I unfortunately can't test if this works due to my PC being broken).

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "*Enter UserName and Password";
                //MessageBox.Show(" Enter UserName and Password .");
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"].ConnectionString))
                {

                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE userName = @Username AND password = @Password", con))
                    {
                        // If these two lines don't work, replace "Username" and "Password" with "@Username"/"@Password"
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", txtUserName.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Password", txtPassword.Text);
                        SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if(r.HasRows())
                        {
                            // this assumes that there is only one user/password and no two users with same UID and PWORD
                            this.Hide();
                            Home hm = new Home();
                            hm.Show();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            lblError.Text = "*Not Registered User or Invalid Name/Password";
                            //MessageBox.Show("Not Registered User or Invalid Name/Password");
                            txtPassword.Text = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

This will help prevent against `SqlInjections` as well.

Comment: You should have suggested it as duplicate... Also it is unlikely to help OP assuming `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"]` is null...

Comment: You are right about commenting that it is a duplicate. Given the Xml provided, could we say that this is null?

Comment: I have System.Configuration reference. As well as I use this code `conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MegaPixelBizConn"].ConnectionString;` but error is coming.