# How to put string as connection string to app.config?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to put my connection string on a USB dongle lock and make my app to read connection string from the lock.
But I don't know how to pass the string to ado.net and the connection string placed on app.config.(I'm using ado.net)The following code is my connection string tag:

```
      <connectionStrings><add name="Db_ReceptionEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DBReception.csdl|res://*/Model.DBReception.ssdl|res://*/Model.DBReception.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Db_Reception;user id=sa;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get connection string from App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536715/get-connection-string-from-app-config)

Comment: @john I believe they are totally different.I want to pass connection string when a USB is attached.The post you mentioned is about getting connection string!!!

Comment: That's probably why it says "possible duplicate", don't you think? No need to get angry at people trying to help.

Comment: @john i am not angry at you. I appreciate your attempt to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this helped:

```
   public Db_ReceptionEntities1(string x)
        : base("name=Db_ReceptionEntities1")
    {

        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = x; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to put string as connection string to app.config?

You do not need to read from the dongle and put it into app.config. You can just read from the dongle and give the connection string to your context.

Your connection string looks like an EF database first connection string. The `DbContext` class has a constructor which accepts a connection string name or a full connection string. You can use that and pass the connection string to it.

Create your context like this:

```
public class StackContext : DbContext
{
    public StackContext(string connection) : base(connection)
    {

    }
}
```

Then read the connection string from the dongle and pass it to your context like this:

```
// read from dongle
var connectionString = ...;
var ctx = new StackContext(connectionString);
```

Comment: it didn't help.tnx for your answer

Comment: @sinaghasemizade what do you mean it didnt help?

Comment: I &#39;ve done it but i dont know how it work. Look at my own answer below. @codingyoshi

Comment: Your answer is doing what the base class will do. You need to pass `x` to the base class like I have shown in my answer but I named it `connection`. It has to work because I have done this many times myself.