# How can i save my connection string form to app config file?

Tags: c#

I want to save my full path connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

in my `app.config` file's connection string section from C# Windows Forms textbox.

Like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TRN_DB"
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: so you want to save/display the connection string to windows form textbox?

Comment: What kind of app is this? Windows forms? How is it deployed?

Comment: I want to save db provider, db path and password from windows form text box to  app.config file. I input the full db path with password like this (Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;) in my windows form's textbox and when i click save button it will be save in app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

hi please check this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536715/get-connection-string-from-app-config)

but you can't modify it because it's `read only` and you get this error

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The configuration
>   is read only.'

you can show connectionString in `TextBox` with this code

```
var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TRN_DB"].ConnectionString;
```